# cygwin 3.x mkfifo -m0600 creates named pipe with 0644 permissions

Tags: cygwin

when i ran cygwin 2.x i used `mkfifo -m 0600 file` to create a named pipe with no user and group
permissions.

in the latest cygwin the above command creates device with 0644 permissions. And i cant drop it to 0600:

```
cygcheck.exe -V
cygcheck (cygwin) 3.1.4

$ umask 0077
$ touch somefile; ls -l somefile
-rw------- 1 admin absent 0 may 26 18:15 somefile

$ mkfifo -m 0600 somefifo; ls -l somefifo
prw-r--r-- 1 admin absent 0 may 26 18:16 somefifo

$ chmod 600 somefifo; ls -l somefifo
prw-r--r-- 1 admin absent 0 may 26 18:16 somefifo
```

In old-good cygwin 2.x the command works as expected:

```
$ cygcheck.exe -V
cygcheck (cygwin) 2.9.0

$ umask
0022

$ mkfifo -m 0600 somefifo; ls -l somefifo
prw------- 1 builduser Domain Users 0 May 26 18:21 somefifo
```

Comment: bug report should be reported on the cygwin mailing list https://cygwin.com/lists.html

Answer (score 1):

the bug was fixed @2020-05-28 18:16:39 snapshot

https://cygwin.com/snapshots/